# scrape the data inside <div class="nutrition-label"> using jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, scrape

I want to scrape the data inside `<div class="nutrition-label">`
 using jsoup I am using:
`Element element = doc.select("div.nutrition-label");`
element is always empty, any help?
the website is http://caloriecount.about.com/calories-bananas-i9040
Regards

Comment: You have a typo in your selection syntax, resulting in an empty element. It should be `nutrition`.

Comment: The issue has not been solved even after correcting the typo‏

Answer (score 1):

The site you are requesting does not recognize your useragent, which leads you to an empty element.

Setting the useragent to something like below should render your desired result.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36").get();
        Elements el = doc.select("div.nutrition-label");
```